I forgot to click the link "Yes, I am affiliated" in the paper submission paper, will I lose co-authorship if paper is accepted?
If one omits to verify their co-authorship (at journal submission time) and if the paper is later accepted, could they confirm co-authorship then?

I think it's a good idea to write to the journal about this and ask whether they can change the selection.

That is very unlikely. Authorship is up to the authors unless there is some misconduct with the paper itself. If the paper lists you among the authors then you are an author.
If corrections need to be made they will be time for that as few papers are ever published exactly as submitted.
Note, however, that being listed as an author and verifying affiliation are very different things. If you are not listed in the paper itself, you need to work with co-authors to correct that.

I am listed as an co-author, But when the paper was submitted by my co-author, the journal in question asked me (through an email) to confirm I am a co-author (which I think I did not do)

Send an email back to that editor and clear it up. Not likely a big deal. Note that author verification is a standard practice.

I'd think that the editors might want either a "yes" or a "no", and not a non-response. But, then who knows what their default action might be...

It is good idea to write to the editor about the missing information and have your name included as co-author in view of contributions made towards the work. Good Luck.
